# Check if a target string is in a list of string. Wildcard involved

Tags: c, regex, string

I want to check if a target string (generated by a program) is a valid string based on if it's in a list(hard coded) of valid string:

```
"external/control/device/feedback/usr/*/control/direction"
"internal/control/device/config"
"internal/control/device/opt/bin/lib"
"internal/control/device/message/request"
"internal/control/device/message/response"
"internal/control/device/etc"
"internal/control/device/usr/"
"external/control/device/feedback/control/direction"
"internal/control/device/central"
"external/control/device/feedback/main/left"
"external/control/device/feedback/main/right"
"external/control/device/feedback/usr/ir_sensor/control/left"
"external/control/device/feedback/usr/ir_sensor/control/right"
"external/control/device/feedback/usr/ultrasonic_sensor/control/left"
"external/control/device/feedback/usr/ultrasonic_sensor/control/right"
"external/control/device/feedback/usr/photo_sensor/control/left"
"external/control/device/feedback/usr/photo_sensor/control/right"
"external/control/device/feedback/usr/wheels_front/control/left"
"external/control/device/feedback/usr/wheels_front/control/right"
"external/control/device/feedback/usr/wheels_back/control/left"
"external/control/device/feedback/usr/wheels_back/control/right"
```

Notice that one of the string has a wildcard segment. It can be sensors name such as `ir_sensor`, `ultrasonic_sensor`, `photo_sensor`, `wheel_front`, or `wheel_back`. So, for example,

```
external/control/device/feedback/usr/ir_sensor/control/direction
```

is considered valid since it matches

```
external/control/device/feedback/usr/*/control/direction
```

So far I came up with a naive solution which I do string comparison for the target string and each string from the list. If it does not match, I then check if it matches the format of `external/control/device/feedback/usr/*/control/direction`. But I think this approach is not very neat and efficient. Can I do a better job by using some data structure or hash search to check if the target string is one of the valid string from the list?

My code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 21

typedef struct source_channel {
    char *channel_name;
} source_channel;

int main () {

    source_channel channels[MAX_SIZE];
    channels[0].channel_name = "external/control/device/feedback/usr/*/control/direction";
    channels[1].channel_name = "internal/control/device/config";
    channels[2].channel_name = "internal/control/device/opt/bin/lib";
    channels[3].channel_name = "internal/control/device/message/request";
    channels[4].channel_name = "internal/control/device/message/response";
    channels[5].channel_name = "internal/control/device/etc";
    channels[6].channel_name = "internal/control/device/usr/";
    channels[7].channel_name = "external/control/device/feedback/control/direction";
    channels[8].channel_name = "internal/control/device/central";
    channels[9].channel_name = "external/control/device/feedback/main/left";
    channels[10].channel_name = "external/control/device/feedback/main/right";
    channels[11].channel_name = "external/control/device/feedback/usr/ir_sensor/control/left";
    channels[12].channel_name = "external/control/device/feedback/usr/ir_sensor/control/right";
    channels[13].channel_name = "external/control/device/feedback/usr/ultrasonic_sensor/control/left";
    channels[14].channel_name = "external/control/device/feedback/usr/ultrasonic_sensor/control/right";
    channels[15].channel_name = "external/control/device/feedback/usr/photo_sensor/control/left";
    channels[16].channel_name = "external/control/device/feedback/usr/photo_sensor/control/right";
    channels[17].channel_name = "external/control/device/feedback/usr/wheels_front/control/left";
    channels[18].channel_name = "external/control/device/feedback/usr/wheels_front/control/right";
    channels[19].channel_name = "external/control/device/feedback/usr/wheels_back/control/left";
    channels[20].channel_name = "external/control/device/feedback/usr/wheels_back/control/right";

    // The target_string is generated by another program. 
    // Hard coded here for experimental purpose
    char *target_string = "external/control/device/feedback/usr/lol/control/direction";

    int regcomp_status = -1;
    int regexec_status = -1;
    regex_t regex;

    char *pattern = "external/control/device/feedback/usr/.*/control/direction";

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++){
        if(strcmp(channels[i].channel_name, target_string) == 0){
            printf("found string\n");
        } else {
            regcomp_status = regcomp(&regex,pattern,REG_EXTENDED|REG_NEWLINE);
            if( regcomp_status == 0){
                printf("compiled\n");
                regexec_status = regexec(&regex, target_string, (size_t) 0, NULL, 0);
                if(regexec_status == 0) {
                    printf("found\n");
                    break;
                } else {
                    printf("not found\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // do something else 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're compiling the regex in the body of the loop. You don't have to compile a pattern more than once. And your pattern doesn't change after its assignment.

Comment: You need to pass a flag indicating whether or not the pattern should be treated as a regex. If it isn't a regex, then don't compile it. Instead, especially for long lists, consider sorting the channels and then use `bsearch`. That's especially true if multiple searches must be executed upon a static list of channels.

Answer (score 0):

Since the strings are fixed, the better way to do this is to compile them
into a regex and see if they match the input target.

This may be counter intuitive but involves a single regex check of the input
to validate it.

By running your constant strings through my strings to regex and regex refactor software,
and setting your `*` wildcard field, the regex becomes

```
^(?:external/control/device/feedback/(?:control/direction|main/(?:lef|righ)t|usr/(?:[^/]+?/control/direction|(?:(?:ir|photo|ultrasonic)_sensor|wheels_(?:back|front))/control/(?:lef|righ)t))|internal/control/device/(?:c(?:entral|onfig)|etc|message/re(?:quest|sponse)|opt/bin/lib|usr/))
```

https://regex101.com/r/0WNVnC/1

and makes the need to check each independent strings unnecessary

```
 ^
 (?:
    external/control/device/feedback/
    (?:
       control/direction
     | main/
       (?: lef | righ )
       t
     | usr/
       (?:
          [^/]+? /control/direction
        | (?:
             (?: ir | photo | ultrasonic )
             _sensor
           | wheels_
             (?: back | front )
          )
          /control/
          (?: lef | righ )
          t
       )
    )
  | internal/control/device/
    (?:
       c
       (?: entral | onfig )
     | etc
     | message/re
       (?: quest | sponse )
     | opt/bin/lib
     | usr/
    )
 )
```